# Copy data from multiple tables using insert into select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have three Table DimCity,Product,DimPeriod

I have to copy the data C_ID from DimCity,P_name,P_type from Product,Period_ID from DimPeriod
into FactTable.

i have allready created FactTable and for inserting value i wrote

```
      INSERT INTO [FactTable]
       ([C_ID],[Period_ID],
[P_name],
[P_type])
 select 
      [C_ID] from DimCity
      Union ALL [P_name],[P_type] from Product
      UNION ALL [Period_ID] From DimPeriod
```

but it not works.

Comment: join the source tables (on whatever relating id you have), then select. don't use union here. union is meant to conca't tables/datasets that have the same structure. How does DimCity relate to, product & DimPeriod?

Comment: I dont get you can you explain how to join a then select?

All the tables are individual,none is related to another.

Comment: @SaNa3819 Check my below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   INSERT INTO [FactTable]([C_ID],[Period_ID],[P_name],[P_type])
   SELECT
      [C_ID], [P_name], [P_type],[Period_ID] 
   FROM DimCity,Product,DimPeriod
```

but it's not recommended.

If you have any relation among these table then you can use Join as follows:

```
 INSERT INTO [FactTable]([C_ID],[Period_ID],[P_name],[P_type])
    SELECT
        P.[C_ID], 
        Q.[P_name], Q.[P_type],
        R.[Period_ID] 
    FROM DimCity P Join Product ON 'Condition Here'
         Join DimPeriod ON 'Condition Here'
```